# 11g XE: could not find the given license file

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, ora-06512

I'm trying to create a simple full-text index like this:

```
exec ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_own_lexer', 'AUTO_LEXER');

create index myidx ON tbl(name) 
   INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context PARAMETERS ('LEXER my_own_lexer')
```

Got error:

```
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10502: index IDX does not exist
DRG-00100: internal error, arguments : [50611],[drli.c],[2743],[License Error:
could not find the given license file:
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/ctx/data/inxight/lang/license.dat],[]
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
```

Using BASIC_LEXER instead of AUTO_LEXER - works without errors

centOS, Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Beta

thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Oracle XE 11gR2 is a *beta* product.  But Express Edition is a restricted product, lacking  some of the functionality included in the bigger product.  So this may be a bug or a feature by design.  The licensing documentation doesn't explicitly [mention AUTO_LEXER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#BABJBGGA), which we might expect if Oracle had deliberately excluded it, so "bug" is quite likely.

The best thing to do is raise this question on [the OTN forum for the product](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1378).  Members of the XE team read and respond to user feedback there.